# How to speed up the generation of a latin hypercube (LHS) design

Tags: r, matlab, performance

I'm trying to generate an optimized LHS (Latin Hypercube Sampling) design in R, with sample size N = 400 and d = 7 variables, but it's taking forever. My pc is an HP Z820 workstation with 12 cores, 32 Mb RAM, Windows 7 64 bit, and I'm running Microsoft R Open which is a multicore version of R. The code has been running for half an hour, but I still don't see any results:

```
library(lhs)
lhs_design <- optimumLHS(n = 400, k = 7, verbose = TRUE)
```

It seems a bit weird. Is there anything I could do to speed it up? I heard that parallel computing may help with R, but I don't know how to use it, and I have no idea if it speeds up only code that I write myself, or if it could speed up an existing package function such as `optimumLHS`. I don't have to use the `lhs` package necessarily - my only requirement is that I would like to generate an LHS design which is optimized in terms of S-optimality criterion, maximin metric, or some other similar optimality criterion (thus, not just a vanilla LHS). If worse comes to worst, I could even accept a solution in a different environment than R, but it must be either MATLAB or a open source environment.

Comment: I don't think a parallel solution will apply here, since you would need to retain the location in k dimensional space where each sample point was taken.

Comment: So in your sample code you aren't specifying max sweeps. I think finding non-intersecting points in a hypercube should be relatively fast, so I think the portion that is probably taking a long time is the CP, S-optimality criterion. Even then, it shouldn't (*maybe*) take that long...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little code to check performance.

```
library(lhs)
library(ggplot2)
performance<-c()

for(i in 1:100){

   ptm<-proc.time()
   invisible(optimumLHS(n = i, k = 7, verbose = FALSE))
   time<-print(proc.time()-ptm)[[3]]

   performance<-rbind(performance,data.frame(time=time, n=i))
  }

ggplot(performance,aes(x=n,y=time))+
  geom_point()
```

[image: Performance]

Not looking too good. It seems to me you might be in for a very long wait indeed. Based on the algorithm, I don't think there is a way to speed things up via parallel processing, since to optimize the separation between sample points, you need to know the location of the all the sample points. I think your only option for speeding this up will be to take a smaller sample or get (access)a faster computer. It strikes me that since this is something that only really has to be done once, is there a resource where you could just get a properly sampled and optimized distribution already computed?

[image: final computation time]

So it looks like ~650 hours for my machine, which is very comparable to yours, to compute with n=400.

Comment: Hi thanks for the analysis, I guess times in your plot are in minutes right? I'm curious to know about the exponent in that power curve, I will make a fit to find out (I guess it's 2). Unfortunately I don't know of any resources where I could find a sample of size 400 in 7 variables.  The few places on the Internet where I found LHS designs covered much smaller designs. If you know of sites which I could try, please let me know.

Comment: Time was a actually in seconds, and yea it was an x^2 fit.